# What are some good way to "reimplement" non-fluent interface as fluent one?

Tags: c++, fluent-interface

What I am looking for is, having non-fluent class:

```
class NonFluent {
    int i=0;
public:
    void setValue(int i) {this->i = i;}
    void multiplyValue(int i) {this->i *= i;}
    int getValue() {return this->i;}
};
```

I would like to change `void` methods to actually return reference to `*this`. I know it's impossible to just derive because we can't change just a return type, because C++ won't be able to distinguish function calls.

We could use composition:

```
class Fluent {
    Fluent& setValue(int i) {var.setValue(i); return *this;}
    Fluent& multiplyValue(int i) {var.multiplyValue(i); return *this;}
    int getValue() {return var.getValue();}

private:
    NonFluent var;
};
```

But that is a pain if there are many `void` methods to begin with.
We could also use object editor I asked question about:
[Is Object Editor a good approach if there are multiple member functions to call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140222/is-object-editor-a-good-approach-if-there-are-multiple-member-functions-to-call), but it has many drawbacks.

Do you know any good methods to do this? (without changing non-fluent class directly?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another answer, I took different approach, that results in lowest code addition:

Editor:

```
template <class T>
struct EditorImpl
{
    T* ptr;

    template <class F>
    EditorImpl& operator()(F&& f)
    {
        f(ptr);
        return *this;
    }

    T* yield() const {
        return ptr;
    }
};

template <class T>
EditorImpl<T> Editor(T* ptr) { return EditorImpl<T>{ptr}; }

template <class T>
EditorImpl<T> Editor(T& ref) { return EditorImpl<T>{&ref}; }
```

GET_MACRO (everything is up to 100):

```
namespace detail {
#define GET_MACRO_1(_1, NAME, ...) NAME
#define GET_MACRO_2(_1, _2, NAME, ...) NAME
#define GET_MACRO_3(_1, _2, _3, NAME, ...) NAME
//...
#define GET_MACRO_98(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, _17, _18, _19, _20, _21, _22, _23, _24, _25, _26, _27, _28, _29, _30, _31, _32, _33, _34, _35, _36, _37, _38, _39, _40, _41, _42, _43, _44, _45, _46, _47, _48, _49, _50, _51, _52, _53, _54, _55, _56, _57, _58, _59, _60, _61, _62, _63, _64, _65, _66, _67, _68, _69, _70, _71, _72, _73, _74, _75, _76, _77, _78, _79, _80, _81, _82, _83, _84, _85, _86, _87, _88, _89, _90, _91, _92, _93, _94, _95, _96, _97, _98, NAME, ...) NAME
#define GET_MACRO_99(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, _17, _18, _19, _20, _21, _22, _23, _24, _25, _26, _27, _28, _29, _30, _31, _32, _33, _34, _35, _36, _37, _38, _39, _40, _41, _42, _43, _44, _45, _46, _47, _48, _49, _50, _51, _52, _53, _54, _55, _56, _57, _58, _59, _60, _61, _62, _63, _64, _65, _66, _67, _68, _69, _70, _71, _72, _73, _74, _75, _76, _77, _78, _79, _80, _81, _82, _83, _84, _85, _86, _87, _88, _89, _90, _91, _92, _93, _94, _95, _96, _97, _98, _99, NAME, ...) NAME
#define GET_MACRO_100(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, _17, _18, _19, _20, _21, _22, _23, _24, _25, _26, _27, _28, _29, _30, _31, _32, _33, _34, _35, _36, _37, _38, _39, _40, _41, _42, _43, _44, _45, _46, _47, _48, _49, _50, _51, _52, _53, _54, _55, _56, _57, _58, _59, _60, _61, _62, _63, _64, _65, _66, _67, _68, _69, _70, _71, _72, _73, _74, _75, _76, _77, _78, _79, _80, _81, _82, _83, _84, _85, _86, _87, _88, _89, _90, _91, _92, _93, _94, _95, _96, _97, _98, _99, _100, NAME, ...) NAME
}
```

Macro that generates lambda which calls macro argument on the object:

```
namespace detail {
#define E_1(_1)[](auto* p) {p -> _1; }
#define E_2(_1,_2)[](auto* p) {p -> _1; p -> _2; }
#define E_3(_1,_2,_3)[](auto* p) {p -> _1; p -> _2; p -> _3; }
//...    
#define E_98(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63,_64,_65,_66,_67,_68,_69,_70,_71,_72,_73,_74,_75,_76,_77,_78,_79,_80,_81,_82,_83,_84,_85,_86,_87,_88,_89,_90,_91,_92,_93,_94,_95,_96,_97,_98)[](auto* p) {p -> _1; p -> _2; p -> _3; p -> _4; p -> _5; p -> _6; p -> _7; p -> _8; p -> _9; p -> _10; p -> _11; p -> _12; p -> _13; p -> _14; p -> _15; p -> _16; p -> _17; p -> _18; p -> _19; p -> _20; p -> _21; p -> _22; p -> _23; p -> _24; p -> _25; p -> _26; p -> _27; p -> _28; p -> _29; p -> _30; p -> _31; p -> _32; p -> _33; p -> _34; p -> _35; p -> _36; p -> _37; p -> _38; p -> _39; p -> _40; p -> _41; p -> _42; p -> _43; p -> _44; p -> _45; p -> _46; p -> _47; p -> _48; p -> _49; p -> _50; p -> _51; p -> _52; p -> _53; p -> _54; p -> _55; p -> _56; p -> _57; p -> _58; p -> _59; p -> _60; p -> _61; p -> _62; p -> _63; p -> _64; p -> _65; p -> _66; p -> _67; p -> _68; p -> _69; p -> _70; p -> _71; p -> _72; p -> _73; p -> _74; p -> _75; p -> _76; p -> _77; p -> _78; p -> _79; p -> _80; p -> _81; p -> _82; p -> _83; p -> _84; p -> _85; p -> _86; p -> _87; p -> _88; p -> _89; p -> _90; p -> _91; p -> _92; p -> _93; p -> _94; p -> _95; p -> _96; p -> _97; p -> _98; }
#define E_99(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63,_64,_65,_66,_67,_68,_69,_70,_71,_72,_73,_74,_75,_76,_77,_78,_79,_80,_81,_82,_83,_84,_85,_86,_87,_88,_89,_90,_91,_92,_93,_94,_95,_96,_97,_98,_99)[](auto* p) {p -> _1; p -> _2; p -> _3; p -> _4; p -> _5; p -> _6; p -> _7; p -> _8; p -> _9; p -> _10; p -> _11; p -> _12; p -> _13; p -> _14; p -> _15; p -> _16; p -> _17; p -> _18; p -> _19; p -> _20; p -> _21; p -> _22; p -> _23; p -> _24; p -> _25; p -> _26; p -> _27; p -> _28; p -> _29; p -> _30; p -> _31; p -> _32; p -> _33; p -> _34; p -> _35; p -> _36; p -> _37; p -> _38; p -> _39; p -> _40; p -> _41; p -> _42; p -> _43; p -> _44; p -> _45; p -> _46; p -> _47; p -> _48; p -> _49; p -> _50; p -> _51; p -> _52; p -> _53; p -> _54; p -> _55; p -> _56; p -> _57; p -> _58; p -> _59; p -> _60; p -> _61; p -> _62; p -> _63; p -> _64; p -> _65; p -> _66; p -> _67; p -> _68; p -> _69; p -> _70; p -> _71; p -> _72; p -> _73; p -> _74; p -> _75; p -> _76; p -> _77; p -> _78; p -> _79; p -> _80; p -> _81; p -> _82; p -> _83; p -> _84; p -> _85; p -> _86; p -> _87; p -> _88; p -> _89; p -> _90; p -> _91; p -> _92; p -> _93; p -> _94; p -> _95; p -> _96; p -> _97; p -> _98; p -> _99; }
#define E_100(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63,_64,_65,_66,_67,_68,_69,_70,_71,_72,_73,_74,_75,_76,_77,_78,_79,_80,_81,_82,_83,_84,_85,_86,_87,_88,_89,_90,_91,_92,_93,_94,_95,_96,_97,_98,_99,_100)[](auto* p) {p -> _1; p -> _2; p -> _3; p -> _4; p -> _5; p -> _6; p -> _7; p -> _8; p -> _9; p -> _10; p -> _11; p -> _12; p -> _13; p -> _14; p -> _15; p -> _16; p -> _17; p -> _18; p -> _19; p -> _20; p -> _21; p -> _22; p -> _23; p -> _24; p -> _25; p -> _26; p -> _27; p -> _28; p -> _29; p -> _30; p -> _31; p -> _32; p -> _33; p -> _34; p -> _35; p -> _36; p -> _37; p -> _38; p -> _39; p -> _40; p -> _41; p -> _42; p -> _43; p -> _44; p -> _45; p -> _46; p -> _47; p -> _48; p -> _49; p -> _50; p -> _51; p -> _52; p -> _53; p -> _54; p -> _55; p -> _56; p -> _57; p -> _58; p -> _59; p -> _60; p -> _61; p -> _62; p -> _63; p -> _64; p -> _65; p -> _66; p -> _67; p -> _68; p -> _69; p -> _70; p -> _71; p -> _72; p -> _73; p -> _74; p -> _75; p -> _76; p -> _77; p -> _78; p -> _79; p -> _80; p -> _81; p -> _82; p -> _83; p -> _84; p -> _85; p -> _86; p -> _87; p -> _88; p -> _89; p -> _90; p -> _91; p -> _92; p -> _93; p -> _94; p -> _95; p -> _96; p -> _97; p -> _98; p -> _99; p -> _100; }
}

#define E_(...) GET_MACRO_100(__VA_ARGS__, E_100, E_99, E_98, E_97, E_96, E_95, E_94, E_93, E_92, E_91, E_90, E_89, E_88, E_87, E_86, E_85, E_84, E_83, E_82, E_81, E_80, E_79, E_78, E_77, E_76, E_75, E_74, E_73, E_72, E_71, E_70, E_69, E_68, E_67, E_66, E_65, E_64, E_63, E_62, E_61, E_60, E_59, E_58, E_57, E_56, E_55, E_54, E_53, E_52, E_51, E_50, E_49, E_48, E_47, E_46, E_45, E_44, E_43, E_42, E_41, E_40, E_39, E_38, E_37, E_36, E_35, E_34, E_33, E_32, E_31, E_30, E_29, E_28, E_27, E_26, E_25, E_24, E_23, E_22, E_21, E_20, E_19, E_18, E_17, E_16, E_15, E_14, E_13, E_12, E_11, E_10, E_9, E_8, E_7, E_6, E_5, E_4, E_3, E_2, E_1)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Final macro:

```
namespace detail {
#define EDIT_0(_1 )Editor(_1).yield()
#define EDIT_1(_1,_2)Editor(_1)(E_(_2)).yield()
#define EDIT_2(_1,_2,_3)Editor(_1)(E_(_2,_3)).yield()
#define EDIT_3(_1,_2,_3,_4)Editor(_1)(E_(_2,_3,_4)).yield()
//...
#define EDIT_98(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63,_64,_65,_66,_67,_68,_69,_70,_71,_72,_73,_74,_75,_76,_77,_78,_79,_80,_81,_82,_83,_84,_85,_86,_87,_88,_89,_90,_91,_92,_93,_94,_95,_96,_97,_98,_99)Editor(_1)(E_(_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63,_64,_65,_66,_67,_68,_69,_70,_71,_72,_73,_74,_75,_76,_77,_78,_79,_80,_81,_82,_83,_84,_85,_86,_87,_88,_89,_90,_91,_92,_93,_94,_95,_96,_97,_98,_99)).yield()
#define EDIT_99(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63,_64,_65,_66,_67,_68,_69,_70,_71,_72,_73,_74,_75,_76,_77,_78,_79,_80,_81,_82,_83,_84,_85,_86,_87,_88,_89,_90,_91,_92,_93,_94,_95,_96,_97,_98,_99,_100)Editor(_1)(E_(_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63,_64,_65,_66,_67,_68,_69,_70,_71,_72,_73,_74,_75,_76,_77,_78,_79,_80,_81,_82,_83,_84,_85,_86,_87,_88,_89,_90,_91,_92,_93,_94,_95,_96,_97,_98,_99,_100)).yield()
}
#define EDIT(...) GET_MACRO_100(__VA_ARGS__, EDIT_99, EDIT_98, EDIT_97, EDIT_96, EDIT_95, EDIT_94, EDIT_93, EDIT_92, EDIT_91, EDIT_90, EDIT_89, EDIT_88, EDIT_87, EDIT_86, EDIT_85, EDIT_84, EDIT_83, EDIT_82, EDIT_81, EDIT_80, EDIT_79, EDIT_78, EDIT_77, EDIT_76, EDIT_75, EDIT_74, EDIT_73, EDIT_72, EDIT_71, EDIT_70, EDIT_69, EDIT_68, EDIT_67, EDIT_66, EDIT_65, EDIT_64, EDIT_63, EDIT_62, EDIT_61, EDIT_60, EDIT_59, EDIT_58, EDIT_57, EDIT_56, EDIT_55, EDIT_54, EDIT_53, EDIT_52, EDIT_51, EDIT_50, EDIT_49, EDIT_48, EDIT_47, EDIT_46, EDIT_45, EDIT_44, EDIT_43, EDIT_42, EDIT_41, EDIT_40, EDIT_39, EDIT_38, EDIT_37, EDIT_36, EDIT_35, EDIT_34, EDIT_33, EDIT_32, EDIT_31, EDIT_30, EDIT_29, EDIT_28, EDIT_27, EDIT_26, EDIT_25, EDIT_24, EDIT_23, EDIT_22, EDIT_21, EDIT_20, EDIT_19, EDIT_18, EDIT_17, EDIT_16, EDIT_15, EDIT_14, EDIT_13, EDIT_12, EDIT_11, EDIT_10, EDIT_9, EDIT_8, EDIT_7, EDIT_6, EDIT_5, EDIT_4, EDIT_3, EDIT_2, EDIT_1, EDIT_0)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Example class:

```
class Simple {
    int i=0;
public:
    Simple() : Simple(0) {}
    Simple(int i) {this->i = i;}
    void setValue(int i) {this->i = i;}
    void multiplyValue(int i) {this->i *= i;}
    void halve() {this->i /= 2;}
    int getValue() {return this->i;}

};
```

And after all that madness, the usage:

```
Simple* simple = EDIT(new Simple, setValue(50), multiplyValue(3));
```

That's the best I could do :)

Answer (score 2):

A better approach that you could use with `Fluent`, but not with `NonFluent`, is to make your class *immutable*, and have its methods return new objects with the results of modification:

```
class Fluent {
    static Fluent withValue(int i) {
        NonFluent v;
        v.setValue(i);
        return Fluent(v);
    }
    Fluent multiplyValue(int i) const {
        Fluent res(var);
        res.var.multiplyValue(i);
        return res;
    }
    int getValue() const {return var.getValue;}
private:
    Fluent(const NonFluent& v) : var(v) {}
    NonFluent var;
};
```

Note the static factory method creating `Fluent` objects.

The code using the factory looks like this:

```
int res = Fluent
    .withValue(5)
    .multiplyValue(2)
    .getValue();
```

This gives you a chance to rework the API to include methods taking other fluent objects, like this:

```
Fluent multiply(const Fluent& other) const {
    Fluent res(var);
    res.var.multiplyValue(other.getValue());
    return res;
}
```

The overall result is that your API becomes concurrency-friendly, without changing anything in the original `NonFluent` API.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this for a while, and I was able to make some comfortable syntax for inheritance approach, where fluent methods will begin with `f_`.

Here is some macro magic:

```
#define FIFTHS(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, NAME, ...) NAME
#define MODIFY_ARGS_1(_1_) _1_ _1
#define MODIFY_ARGS_2(_1_, _2_) _1_ _1, _2_ _2
#define MODIFY_ARGS_3(_1_, _2_, _3_) _1_ _1, _2_ _2, _3_ _3
#define MODIFY_ARGS_4(_1_, _2_, _3_, _4_) _1_ _1,  _2_ _2, _3_ _3, _4_ _4
#define MODIFY_ARGS_5(_1_, _2_, _3_, _4_, _5_) _1_ _1,  _2_ _2, _3_ _3, _4_ _4, _5_ _5
#define MODIFY_ARGS(...) FIFTHS(__VA_ARGS__, MODIFY_ARGS_5, MODIFY_ARGS_4, MODIFY_ARGS_3, MODIFY_ARGS_2, MODIFY_ARGS_1)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define SEQUENCE_1(_1_) _1
#define SEQUENCE_2(_1_, _2_) _1, _2
#define SEQUENCE_3(_1_, _2_, _3_) _1, _2, _3
#define SEQUENCE_4(_1_, _2_, _3_, _4_) _1,  _2, _3, _4
#define SEQUENCE_5(_1_, _2_, _3_, _4_, _5_) _1,  _2, _3, _4, _5
#define SEQUENCE(...) FIFTHS(__VA_ARGS__, SEQUENCE_5, SEQUENCE_4, SEQUENCE_3, SEQUENCE_2, SEQUENCE_1)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define FLUENTIZE_DERIVE() CONCATENATE(Fluent,CURRENT_BASE) : public CURRENT_BASE
#define FLUENTIZE_METHOD(name, ...) CONCATENATE(Fluent,CURRENT_BASE)& f_ ## name (MODIFY_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)) {name(SEQUENCE(__VA_ARGS__)); return *this;}
#define FLUENTIZE_PROCEDURE(name) CONCATENATE(Fluent,CURRENT_BASE)& f_ ## name() {name(); return *this;}
#define FLUENTIZE_DFLT_CONSTRUCTOR(name) CONCATENATE(Fluent,CURRENT_BASE)() {}
#define FLUENTIZE_CONSTRUCTOR(...) CONCATENATE(Fluent,CURRENT_BASE)(MODIFY_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)) : CURRENT_BASE(SEQUENCE(__VA_ARGS__)) {}
```

Note: `_x_` stands for type, and `_x` stands for argument name.

Now, we have non-fluent class:

```
class Simple {
    int i=0;   
public:
    Simple() : Simple(0) {}
    Simple(int i) {this->i = i;}
    void setValue(int i) {this->i = i;}
    void multiplyValue(int i) {this->i *= i;}
    void halve() {this->i /= 2;}
    int getValue() {return this->i;}

};
```

And that's how to recreate fluent class:

```
#define CURRENT_BASE Simple
class FLUENTIZE_DERIVE() {
public:
    FLUENTIZE_DFLT_CONSTRUCTOR()
    FLUENTIZE_CONSTRUCTOR(int)
    FLUENTIZE_METHOD(setValue, int)
    FLUENTIZE_METHOD(multiplyValue, int)
    FLUENTIZE_PROCEDURE(halve)
};
#undef CURRENT_BASE
```

With that, we created class named `FluentSimple`, with fluent methods `f_setValue`,`f_multiplyValue` and `f_halve`. With some macro magic I automatically named function arguments (arguments are named as sequence `_1, _2, _3 ...`, up to `_5` for testing). Note that I had to make another macro for methods that don't take any arguments because macro technique that I used can't deal with empty `__VA_ARGS__` macro.

Now, thats how to use the fluent class:

```
std::cout << 
FluentSimple()
    .f_setValue(10)
    .f_multiplyValue(10)
    .f_halve()
    .getValue() << std::endl;
```

Also note that with this construction, fluent class has access to all base class methods and some features like Qt slots and signals.

If it has any drawbacks, except usage of macros, please let me know :)